# Excel, Create a named range from the contents of cells usign cell formulas

Tags: excel, formula

I am stuck...

I have a 100 Row sheet with 10 Columns.  This list is broken into classes simply by inline headers. I have definitions of the blocks of data under each head, for example:
UNASSOCIATED  A2  A19
HOSTS   A21   A32
ROOF    A34  A100

I compute those ranges as they may change from time to time. I need
first: Define Name of each group by formula
Second: From time to time select the defined group

I am unable to get a formula to work which will allow me to use the "Content" of the cell as opposed to the cell location to define these ranges.

I'm stuck.

Suggestions would be appreciated.

Regards,
RHD

Comment: Thanks officer but I am not sure what code you wish for me to post?

Answer (score 0):

This cannot be done in a cell formula. You'll need to create a macro (VBA) to do this. Essentially, what you need is to grab the value of a cell then use that value as if it were a cell address.

Take a look at the example macro below. If cell A1 contains the characters "B22", then x will become the value of A1 (which is "B22") and "test" will be written to cell B22. This cannot be done in with cell formulas.

```
Sub test()
    Dim x As String
    x = Range("A1").Value
    Range(x).Value = "test"
End Sub
```

A good amount of adaptation will been needed to incorporate this technique, and you'll need to play with this a bit. Ping this community to help answer more specific questions as they come up.

Comment: Thank you very much.  Wish it was within my abilities to do VBA.  I really appreciate the help.

Comment: You're welcome. It's totally doable. I taught myself when I faced your exact problem. Tenacity and google fu goes a long way.